# Yeoman deploy in heroku doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, heroku, yeoman

I'm having problems with the deploy on heroku, I have an app in yeoman is a angularjs app, this is the heroku logs:

```
2016-02-09T01:58:17.951509+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2016-02-09T01:58:19.647127+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:341
2016-02-09T01:58:19.647138+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2016-02-09T01:58:19.647139+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2016-02-09T01:58:19.647141+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/app.js'
2016-02-09T01:58:19.647140+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-02-09T01:58:19.647142+00:00 app[web.1]:at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
2016-02-09T01:58:19.647142+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
```

and I have a Procfile

```
web: node app.js
```

> and I deleted dist in the .gitignore

Update: Now I can see a blank page but just with this message:

`Cannot GET /`

and in my heroku logs something like that:

```
2016-02-09T03:54:53.259242+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node web.js`
2016-02-09T03:54:55.427994+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:341
2016-02-09T03:54:55.428078+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2016-02-09T03:54:55.428091+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2016-02-09T03:54:55.428114+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'logfmt'
```

I'm searching different solutions but I can't find the right answer.

thanks for the time and Regards !